# How to create a new address for each controller in Swagger

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, controller, swagger

I have two controllers called `TestController` and `Test2Controller`. How can I do in swagger that these two controllers come in 2 separate urls, for example for `TestController` its address with
**baseurl/docs/test/index.html**
And for `Test2Controller` address it with
**baseurl/docs/test2/index.html**

**TestController:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Test")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

**Test2Controller:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Test2")]
public class Test2Controller : ControllerBase
{
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

**StartUp.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("Test", new OpenApiInfo());
            c.SwaggerDoc("Test2", new OpenApiInfo());
        }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
     app.UseSwagger();
     app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
     {
         c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/Test/swagger.json", "Test");
         c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/Test2/swagger.json", "Test2");
     });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Decorate the methods/controller with routing attributes; your swagger generator will pick it up

Comment: Can you give an example? @CaiusJard

Comment: Do you want 2 different Swagger URL for 2 different controllers?

Comment: yes @subhankars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of achieving the URL route you have mentioned. However you can group them and have different Swagger document for 2 different controllers.
Follow the below steps:

**Step 1:** Group your controllers in ApiExplorer Settings as below and give a group name.

```
''--- Controller 1
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "test1")]
    public class TestController1 : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
     }

''--- Controller 2
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "test2")]
    public class TestController2 : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
     }
```

**Step2:** Add two swagger document in AddSwaggerGen in ConfigureServices at startup.cs

```
                services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
                c.SwaggerDoc("test1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "test1",
                    Version = "v1"
                });
                c.SwaggerDoc("test2", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "test2",
                    Version = "v2"
                });
            });
```

**Step 3:** Configure AddSwaggerUI endpoint

```
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/test1/swagger.json", "test1");
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/test2/swagger.json", "test2");
            });
```

After this configuration when you run your Swagger document with https://baseurl/swagger you will see 2 options on your right corner to select a defination
[image]

You can use the following URLs now to access controller specific swagger documents

```
https://baseurl/swagger/index.html?urls.primaryName=test1 -- test controller1  
https://baseurl/swagger/index.html?urls.primaryName=test2 -- test controller2
```

Similarly, to access the Swagger json file use the URLs as below

```
https://baseurl/swagger/test1/swagger.json -- test controller1
https://baseurl/swagger/test2/swagger.json -- test controller2
```

Comment: For your TestController use [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Test")] and for your Test2Controller use [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Test2")]. Your GroupName should match SwaggerDoc and SwagerUI names.

Comment: Follow Step 2: You need to provide Title for each document in AddSwaggerGen c.SwaggerDoc("test1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "Test"
                });
                c.SwaggerDoc("Test2", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "Test2"
                });